# MongoDB - Query collection's array contains all element in input array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have those documents below:

```
[
  {
    array : ['a', 'b' , 'c'],
  },
  {
    array : ['b', 'd' , 'e'],
  },
  {
    array : ['d', 'e' , 'f'],
  },
]
```

and input array for query:

```
["b","d","e","f"]
```

Expected output:

```
['b', 'd' , 'e'],['d', 'e' , 'f']
```

Which query can I use to do that?
And how to filter which element is not in the document?

Expected result:

```
[
  {
     array : ['b', 'd' , 'e'],
     missingElement : ['f']
  },
  {
     array : ['d', 'e' , 'f'],
     missingElement : ['b']
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$expr` - Allow to use aggregation operator.

   1.1. `$eq` - Compare the result from *1.1.1* and *1.1.2* are equal.

   1.1.1. `$size` - Get the size of `array` field.

   1.1.2. `$size` - Get the size of array from the result *1.1.2.1*.

   1.1.2.1. `$setIntersection` - Intersect `array` field and input array, return the intersected value(s) in array.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $size: "$array"
      },
      {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: [
            "$array",
            [
              "b",
              "d",
              "e",
              "f"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vtNhN00FasF)

---

**Updated**

For Aggregation query to find missing element(s):

1. `$match` - Filter the documents (as explained in the first answer for `$expr`).
2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents. For `missingElement` field, you need `$filter` operator to find each value in the input array does not exist (`$not` and `$in`) in the `array`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$array"
          },
          {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$array",
                [
                  "b",
                  "d",
                  "e",
                  "f"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      array: 1,
      missingElement: {
        $filter: {
          input: [
            "b",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f"
          ],
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$this",
                "$array"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Aggregation query)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IOE5IowULEB)

Comment: It's worked. Thank you so much. Can I use aggregation to filter which element is not in the document? I edited my question. Can you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, ya, aggregation query will be easier to achieve. You may refer to this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IOE5IowULEB).